# Unterschiede zwischen "impliziert/bedingt sich gegenseitig/wechselseitig"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich sehe die Phrasen oben oft in der Umgangssprache synonym benutzt. Wenn man zwei Faktoren hat, die sich gegenseitig/wechselseitig bedingen/implizieren, wird es anscheinend so verstanden, dass das Auftreten des einen Faktors das des anderen notwendigerweise nach sich zieht (z. B. Arbeitslosigkeit – Rezession (Arbeitslosigkeit kann ja auch durch falsche Bildungspolitik/Fachkräftemangel entstehen und dann Rezession implizieren). Der Faktor wird meiner Meinung nach als *logisch hinreichend* (Unterschied zu *notwendig*!) betrachtet.

Ich will jetzt gar nicht andeuten, wo Unterschiede liegen könnten, und somit die Antworten beeinflussen, denn das täte mich gerade interessieren, ob ihr hier Bedeutungsunterschiede bei

> wechselseitig bedingen/implizieren und gegenseitig bedingen/implizieren

seht. Vor allem, wenn es dann um drei oder vier Faktoren geht (Netzwerk), die sich beeinflussen. Heißt es z. B., wenn drei Faktoren sich gegenseitig/wechselseitig implizieren/bedingen, dass das Auftreten bereits eines Faktors beide anderen hervorruft, weil alle wie in einem Netzwerk direkt miteinander verbunden sind oder aber nur alle indirekt miteinander verbunden sind und sich somit triggern können (kein Dreieck)?

Die professionellen Programmierer, die wir hier haben, müssen sich soviel ich weiß ja auch mit Netzwerk- und Graphentheorie beschäftigen; ich denke, da werden evtl. zwischen obigen Phrasen semantische Nuancen auftreten. In der Philosophie/Logiktheorie werden soviel ich weiß meist nur zwei Faktoren betrachtet, da hab ich nicht viel Erhellendes gefunden.

---

on comments:

Also ganz einfach: Können die obigen Phrasenkombinationen oben beliebig benutzt werden, ohne dass sich feine Bedeutungsunterschiede, v. a. für den Fall von drei oder mehr Faktoren, ergeben? Alles andere sind Hinweise, die ich für den Nicht-Fall gegeben habe.

Bei drei oder mehr Faktoren muss aber nicht jeder Knoten mit einem anderen verbunden sein, ohne dass man nicht mehr von einem Knoten über Umwege zu irgendeinem anderen gelangen könnte und nicht direkt. **Des Weiteren könnte man *bedingen* in der Netzwerkperspektive so verstehen, dass alle Faktoren, nur unter Bedingung des Auftretens aller einzelnen Faktoren für sich, sich dann gegenseitig beeinflussen, während *implizieren* (hervorrufen) bedeutet, dass egal, welcher Faktor zuerst auftritt (z. B. Rezession), dieser unweigerlich die anderen nach sich zieht.**

user unknowns Kommentar geht meiner Meinung nach schon in die richtige Richtung. Der Duden gibt die einzelnen Begriffe als synonym aus und ist keine große Hilfe für Fachsprache, was den Kontext angeht. **[Auf linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/wechselseitig+bedingen.html) sieht man auch nochmal, wie unterschiedlich das ins Englische übersetzt wird; ob da *dependent, interdependent, relating* logisch alle völlig synonym sind, wage ich zu bezweifeln.** Wahrscheinlich tritt dieser semantische Unterschied nur in Fachwissenschaften wie evtl. Netzwerk-/Systemtheorie auf.

Die Tatsache, dass egal welche Phrasenkombination man oben googelt, alle viele Hits aufweisen, ist vielleicht Indiz für Synonymie, genauso könnte man aber auch fragen, warum hat sich eine dann nicht deutlich durchgesetzt? Evtl. gibt es doch feine Nuancen. Interessiert hier vielleicht wenige, mich aber.

Comment: Das *Ei und die Henne* **bedingen** sich wechselseitig - Aber sie **implizieren** sich nicht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In der Logik verwendet man

> A bedingt B

gleichbedeutend mit

> B impliziert A

also B setzt A voraus, was etwas untergeht, wenn es eine gegenseitige Beziehung sein soll, weil dann auch A B vorraussetzt.

Wenn A B voraussetzt und vice versa, dann können A und B nur gemeinsam auftreten, und dann sind sie das Gleiche.

> A > B impliziert B < A und umgekehrt, sowie A != B

wäre eine solche Konstruktion mit drei Aussagen, die letztlich das Gleiche sagen.

Wenn aber eines ein anderes hervorruft, dann kann es keine wechselseitige Beziehung sein. Wenn ich ein hartes Ei in den Salat schneiden will, dann muss ich das Ei vorher kochen, aber nicht umgekehrt: Ich kann das Ei auch kochen, ohne es anschließend in den Salat zu schneiden. Hier liegt einmal eine Kausalität vor, eine Ursache-Wirkung-Beziehung, aber es ist keine Identität.

Aus A > B und B > C folgt A > C.

Aber aus A > B und A > C folgt nichts über die Beziehung zwischen B und C.

In Wirtschaftskreisläufen finden sich häufig Beziehungen, bei denen die Folgen eines Effektes diesen verstärken, z.B. befördert die Rezession die Arbeitslosigkeit, und jene senkt die Kaufkraft, die Nachfrage, und verstärkt die Rezession, aber wie man leicht sieht, muss die Rezession doch irgendwann angefangen haben, und kann die Nachfrage nur begrenzt zurückgehen. Es muss also weitere Effekte und Gegenkräfte geben – zum Beispiel sinkende Preise, die den Export beflügeln, und damit der Rezession entgegenwirken. Die Begriffe können hier also nicht so streng verwendet werden wie in der Logik oder der Mathematik.

Es ist aber sehr hilfreich sich dieser Betrachtung bewusst zu sein, wenn man vermeiden will, von anderen aufs rhetorische Glatteis geführt zu werden, oder derartige Ausflüge selbst zu veranstalten beabsichtigt.

Comment: Der letzte Satz gefällt mir besonders, da man als Laie auf einem speziellen Gebiet dann oft leichtgläubig erst garnicht weiter nachdenkt, ob besagte Faktoren wirklich unzertrennlich zusammenhängen(weil intuitiv stimmig) und was eigentlich was bedingt/begrenzt/vorraussetzt. In diesem Mischmasch scheinen obige Phrasen aber gerade oft genutzt zu werden als Totschlagargument bzw. um eine starke Verflechtung von Faktoren anzudeuten,ohne sie aber exakt benennen zu wollen/können oder eben fälschlich so darzustellen. Vielleicht sollte man in diesen Fällen eher *voneinander abhängige Faktoren* benutzen

Comment: Ich würde die Antwort dahingehend verbessern, dass die Aussage "A bedingt B" durch ein "ausschließlich A bedingt B" ersetzt wird, denn andernfalls ist die Schlußfolgerung "B impliziert A" nicht gültig. Mit Deiner Abstraktion wären falsche Implikationen konstruierbar. Beispiel: Wenn die Glühbirne kaputt ist, leuchtet die Tischlampe nicht. Aber wenn die Tischlampe nicht leuchtet, impliziert das eben nicht automatisch eine defekte Glühbirne. Es könnte auch ein Stromausfall sein.

Comment: Das ist richtig. Auch sehe ich, dass A != B nicht gleichbedeutend ist mit A > B. Muss ich irgendwie noch rausarbeiten. Allerdings scheint mir 'ausschließlich' nicht der richtige Weg.

Answer (score -1):

In meinem Verständnis gilt: "A bedingt B" = "A hat B zur (Vor-)Bedingung" = "A setzt B voraus" = "A impliziert B" und nur so habe ich das in (einfacheren) mathematischen Büchern auch gefunden.

Comment: Das läßt leider das "gegenseitig" vollkommen außer acht. Im rein mathematischen Sinn ergibt das einen Deadlock.

Comment: Tofro hat recht. Der Fokus der Frage liegt eindeutig auf *wechselseitig* und *gegenseitig*. Diesen Aspekt ignoriert deine leider auch ziemlich kurze Antwort völlig.